# Variants of <% when writing code inside views in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm currently learning MVC2, and I have seen three variants of the tags that contain the actual code for a View:

```
<% ... %>
```

With a = after the %

```
<%= ... %>
```

and with a : after the %

```
<%: ... %>
```

What is the difference of these three code containers?

And are there any other variants of these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<% ...  %>
```

is just a block of code

```
<%: "blah blah" %>
```

Is Shorthand for

```
<%= Html.Encode("blah blah") %>
```

Which is shorthand for

```
<% Response.Write(Html.Encode("blah blah")) %>
```

Comment: That sums it up nicely! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1.`<% ... %>` just block of code

```
<%if (Model.HelloWorld != null){%>
Hello World!!
<%} %>
```

2.`<%= ... %>` plain text without escaping

```
<%=Model.HelloWorld %>
```

3.`<%: ... %>` text with escaping  equal `<%= Server.HtmlEncode(Model.Something) %>` Details [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

```
<%:Model.HelloWorld %>
```